# Git Laravel Project on windows server

Tags: git, laravel, windows-server-2012

I am using windows server 2012 standard

and I hosted my website project that use git, with laravel 5.4

in 127.0.0.1:8000 it works fine and read .git repositories

but when I access the website from out side the localhost, it sees ''git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'

in 127.0.0.1:8000 it dose not display this message

how to fix this?

Comment: "when I access the website from out side the localhost" how do you access your site external and where are you running got command

Answer (score 0):

> ''git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.'

That means the environment you are using to access your git repo does not have Git installed (ir git in the user PATH)

So depending on your actual workstation (PC or Linux), double-check your PATH.